# How can I convert class properties into uppercase and rename few without Attribute in elasticsearch with c#

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using elasticsearch in C# to put some data into elasticsearch. I have kept my C# class & properties as per database (PascalCase). However, my requirement is to convert all properties into Uppercase and also change the name of few to another name. Same should be possible for class name as well.

I do not want to achieve this via Data annotations. Is there any way which can be made generic for all C# classes?

I am using NEST 5.X version.

For example,

```
class Foo 
{
     public string thisMessage {get; set; }
     public string anotherMessage {get; set; }
}
```

should convert into

```
class FOOABC
{
    public string THISMESSAGE {get; set; }
    public string ANOTHER {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the old documents too?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking; Do you want to change the source code for the types, or do you want to control how they are serialized to json, to control the `_type` and field properties for each property on your C# POCO?

Comment: I just want to rename properties and change these to uppercase before indexing to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do both with NEST without using attributes:

1. to change the casing of POCO property names when serialized and sent to Elasticsearch, use `DefaultFieldNameInferrer(Func<string, string>)`
2. to change the name of the type and rename properties, use `InferMappingFor<T>()` with `TypeName()` and `Rename()`

Here's an example

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(s => s.ToUpperInvariant())
        .InferMappingFor<Foo>(m => m
            .TypeName("FOOABC")
            .Rename(p => p.anotherMessage, "ANOTHER")
        )
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var indexResponse = client.Index(new Foo
    {   
        thisMessage = "this message",
        anotherMessage = "another message"
    });
}

class Foo
{
    public string thisMessage { get; set; }
    public string anotherMessage { get; set; }
}
```

the index request and response

```
POST http://localhost:9200/default-index/FOOABC?pretty=true 
{
  "THISMESSAGE": "this message",
  "ANOTHER": "another message"
}

Status: 201
{
  "_index" : "default-index",
  "_type" : "FOOABC",
  "_id" : "AVtaHKDcii5CLKx9KIcZ",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "created" : true
}
```